# AS3 Error: '1172: Definition fl.controls:Button could not be found.'

Tags: actionscript-3, button, class, definition

I am trying to create a class called LinkButton, which is a simple class that loads a URL on a click *(im doing this to simpify my designers' transition to AS3)*.  Even though I am importing the button definition, the AS file gets a compile error: ***1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Button.*** and ***1172: Definition fl.controls:Button could not be found.*** I created the button by making a simple shape converting it to a symbol (F8) of type 'Button'. In my FLA file i have this code:

```
import AS3classes.mouse.LinkButton;
var link1:LinkButton = new LinkButton(testLink, "http://www.example.com");
```

Simple right? In my AS file I am importing the button definition, declaring the constructor and 'linkTo' Behaviour. Here is my code in the AS file:

```
package AS3classes.mouse
{
 import fl.controls.Button;
 import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;

 public class LinkButton 
 {
  private var _pageURL:String;
  private var _button:Button;

  public function LinkButton(button, pageURL) : void
  {
   _button = button;
   _pageURL = pageURL;
   _button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, LinkTo);
  }

  private function LinkTo(e:Event) : void
  {
   var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(_pageURL);
  }
 }
}
```

When I Google this, I see people getting this error because they don't have a button in their library.  I do have a button I created from a simple shape. Am I importing the right definition? I have no problem importing the movieClip definition in a different script with the same method. I don't understand the difference, and I'm pretty sure I'm not stupid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the wrong type of button.  As you describe it, you want

```
flash.display.SimpleButton
```

`fl.controls.Button` is a Button component, not a button defined in the library.  Make sense?  Try importing flash.display.SimpleButton and setting _button to be a SimpleButton instead.

Comment: THANK YOU!!  This is the exact info I needed.

Answer (score 6):

You need to go to the *"Components"* window and drag a *"Button"* onto your *"Library"* window.

To use the component, simply import it using the `import fl.controls.Button;` instruction.
You can now use the *"Button"* with its label and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Matt Dales - is right. I just now had the exact problem. The "Button" fooled me. In ctrl+f7 = components panel, I looked in the Video group and tried a button from there. Doesn't work as a "Button". Look in the "User Interface" group. Get the "Button" from there and drag into the Library. Then fl.controls.Button and Button() work.